# Showing that the direct product does not satisfy the universal property of the direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

I feel intuitively that for $\prod_{i\in \mathbb N}\mathbb{Z}$, as a $\mathbb{Z}$−module, and $\phi_i:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ the identity map, more than one homomorphism $\phi:\prod_{i\in \mathbb N}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the condition "composition with the canonical embedding yields the identity map $\phi_i:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$". But I can't myself define such homomorphisms $\phi:\prod_{i\in \mathbb N}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$.

Could anyone suggest some appropriate functions?

Comment: By $N$ you mean the set of natural numbers?

Answer (score 1):

It is a well-known result by Specker ([original reference](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-9259-9_5),  [MO/10239](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239)) that homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ are determined by what they do on the $e_i=(\delta_{ij})_j$ and that almost all $e_i$ are mapped to zero. In particular, there is no homomorphism mapping all $e_i \mapsto 1$.

Comment: where can I find the proof about there is no homomorphism mapping all e i ↦1? The original reference seems to be written in German..Could you suggest me some English links?

Comment: I have included a link to MO.

Comment: Oh didn't recognize it. Thank you :)